# Как спрятать клавиатуру при запуске активити?

Tags: android

Как спрятать клавиатуру при запуске активити на котором есть EditText или может поставить фокус на другой элемент?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В манифесте пропишите для Вашей активити свойство: `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`

Comment: спасибо, сработало!

Answer (score 6):

Скрыть клавиатуру можно следующим образом:

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) YourActivity.this.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(YourActivity.this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

А если хотите убрать фокус с `EditText`, то контейнеру, в котором он находится, добавьте два атрибута:

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

А вообще, странно, при старте приложения, у меня фокус на `EditText`, но клавиатура автоматически не открывается.

Comment: программно крашится, а через xml не ничего не маняеться. Спасибо, инфа также полезная

Comment: Поддерживаю, крашится на 26 API - NullPointerException