# Убрать клавиатуру при запуске активности

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Как убрать авто-поднятие клавиатуры при входе в приложение и тд. или можно убрать авто-фокус на editText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый вариант:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
assert imm != null;
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditText.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Второй вариант:

Пропишите в манифесте для вашей активности атрибут
`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`

Comment: Ваш код не помог, всё равно при запуске клавиатура появляется

Comment: Странно, у меня работает. Попробуйте добавить в xml `EditText` атрибут `android:focusable="true"`

Comment: очень интересно, но даже это не помогает

Comment: тогда тут посмотрите первый ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/574626/Как-спрятать-клавиатуру-при-запуске-активити :)

Comment: Ура! Помогло, спасибо

Comment: дополнил ответ. Пжлста)